# MVC 6 security adding a policy is not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

I am following the documentation [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html) and [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html#security-authorization-policies-based-authorization-handler) to go with claims based approach to security. The code in the documentation does not compile.

On this line

```
options.AddPolicy("Over21",
                          policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Authorization.MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
    });
```

I get a compile time error:
The type `MinimumAgeRequirement` does not exist in the type `Authorization`
Here is a screenshot of that.

[image]

While trying to follow the simpler example [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html)

I get an error as below on hitting F5:

[image]

Is there a full working example somewhere? The documentation seems half baked.

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's custom class that's been built for this example.

It's right in the [page you linked](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html#requirements):

```cs
public class MinimumAgeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public MinimumAgeRequirement(int age)
    {
        MinimumAge = age;
    }

    protected int MinimumAge { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to create your handler too:

```cs
public class MinimumAgeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>
{
    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth &&
                                   c.Issuer == "http://contoso.com"))
        {
            return;
        }

        var dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(context.User.FindFirst(
            c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth && c.Issuer == "http://contoso.com").Value);

        int calculatedAge = DateTime.Today.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
        if (dateOfBirth > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-calculatedAge))
        {
            calculatedAge--;
        }

        if (calculatedAge >= MinimumAge)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}
```

Your final code should look like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Over21",
                      policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Authorization.MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
});
services.AddInstance<IAuthorizationHandler>(new Authorization.MinimumAgeHandler());
```

Comment: both the custom class and it handler already are existing. Sorry I forgot to mention that earlier. Even then I get error as in the updated screenshot above in my question. How is it possible for the `MinimumAgeHandler` to be available on the `Authorization` type? I am not creating an extention method on the type `Authorization`.

Comment: Turns out `Authorization` was a namespace in the documentation that I followed. Removed it and it compiled. Now to look at the other problems.

Comment: If my answer matched your original question, don't forget to mark it as answered. This will help future user with the same issue that you had.

Comment: @MaximeRouiller-MVP What version of ASP.NET Core does this work in? I Can't seem to get it working in RC1

Comment: @rob Based on the date of my posting, I think it's `beta8`. I would check the following page for more information: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html